# CSS Background Image not Showing

Tags: html, css

Hi I am trying to show my background image for the div called #container but it is not working why?

When I try to set the background color it works perfectly... I have tried to use

'/pics/coffey.jpg'

pics/coffey.jpg

"/pics/coffey.jpg"

"../pics/coffey.jpg"

But the picture is lying like this /css/pics/coffey.jpg

And my style file is in the css folder so it should work with /pics/coffey.jpg but it doesn't anyone help??

CSS:

```
#container {
width : 740px;
height:200px;
margin-left : auto;
margin-right : auto;
margin-top : 20px;
line-height: 1.7em;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-image: url("/pics/coffey.jpg");
}
#topbar {
    height:20px;
    width:740px;
    float:right;
    font-size:10px;
    font-family:Verdana;
    font-style:italic;
    padding:0px;
    background:#644C37;

}
```

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="sv">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Lorem Ipsum</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/basic.css" />
</head>

<body>

    <div id="container">
        <div id="topbar">   
            "Quisque sit amet justo"
        </div>

        <div id="menu">

            <a href="#maincontent">Skip navigation</a>

            <ul>
                <li class="active"><a href="#">hem</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">projekt</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">information</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">kontakt</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">hitta till oss</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <div id="maincontent">
                <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>

                <img src="pics/info.jpg" alt="Bubblande kaffe" />
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Pellentesque tincidunt volutpat nunc. Curabitur id dolor sed massa volutpat mollis. Duis lorem diam, vestibulum pharetra, consequat ac, semper ac, nibh. Integer vel pede ac purus aliquet nonummy. In hendrerit. Praesent posuere, tellus eget nonummy pellentesque, tellus eros bibendum erat, non hendrerit erat eros sed lorem. Sed pretium quam sed lacus. Maecenas turpis tellus, feugiat a, ultrices a, porta ac, nisi. Donec convallis neque. Nam lobortis nibh sit amet metus tincidunt faucibus. Sed nec leo. Aliquam mattis.</p>
            </div>

            <div id="subcontent">

                <h1>Quisque</h1>    
                <p>Quisque sit amet justo. Maecenas eu nibh ut est tincidunt congue. Vivamus quis diam. Curabitur lobortis pede eu turpis. Nulla adipiscing. Phasellus risus arcu, malesuada eu, molestie et, cursus vel, nisl. Aliquam at est. Nullam nec lacus. Nulla vitae justo. Donec volutpat elit ut orci.</p>

                <h2>Read more:</h2>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">http://www.saadsa.fds</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">http://www.llsd.seafa/seas</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">http://consecyt.hg</a></li>
                    </ul>

            </div>
            <div id="bottomcontent">&copy; Linnéuniversitetet, Institutionen för datavetenskap</div>
        </div>      
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: if you have folder structure like this:  
- pics  
-- coffey.jpg  
- css  
--style.css  
index.html  
  
then in style.css you must write ../pics/coffey.jpg

Comment: `url("/pics/coffey.jpg");` in your `css` specifies that `pics` directory is on the `root`, but it is inside `css` directory actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/css/pics/coffey.jpg

is the correct path

Comment: That was stupid of me I should have realized that you go from the index.html...... thanks